# Сделать накопительный столбец в датафрейме

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

В датафрейм df Нужно добавить столбик с накоплением данных от другого столбца,
я его сейчас добавил вручную это quantity_sum. Он накапливает сумму от quantity
Как сделать это быстро и правильно? по Питоновски)) ?

```
        date    quantity    quantity_sum
0   2021-12-30  2  2
1   2021-12-31  1  3
2   2022-01-01  1  4
3   2022-01-02  3  7
4   2022-01-03  1  8
5   2022-01-04  1  9
6   2022-01-05  1  10
7   2022-01-06  1  11
8   2022-01-07  1  12
9   2022-01-08  1  13
10  2022-01-09  1  14
11  2022-01-10  1  15
12  2022-01-11  1  16
13  2022-01-12  1  17
```

Comment: В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 df['quantity_sum'] = df['quantity'].cumsum()
```

Для решения этой задачи, оказывается есть стандартный метод. Проще и быстрее быть не может

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).